# can't execute function returned in variable php

Tags: php, function, variables, syntax

I have a function with this syntaxe :

```
$variable = function() {
    return function(){
        //code
    }
}
```

I can't execute that function with

```
$variable()
```

Is there a way to execute this function ?

Comment: You don't make a call to the inner function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know for what is it... But here example:

```
$a = function () {
   return function () { 
       return 1; 
   };
};
$b = $a();
echo $b();
```

Comment: Or in PHP7 `$b = $a()()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your anonymous function (outer function), stored in a `$variable` returns another function (inner function).

Calling `$variable()` means that outer function returns inner one. See - **returns**, not **executes**. But as you don't assign result of outer function to any variable, your inner function is not stored anywhere.

So, the solution is:

```
$res = $variable();  // res stores an inner function
$res();
```

Or (in PHP7)

```
$variable()();
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is returning and the calling is not doing anything with it use echo:

```
echo $variable();
```

I would suggest having separate functions instead for clarity.

```
$variable = doSomething();

function doeSomething(){
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without assing to new variable you can do this:

`call_user_func($variable());`